# RxJS skipWhile boolean is true

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following use-case:

There is a service which queues calculation tasks with a certain ID. I hooked up an observable to query the status of the service. As long as the ID is in the queue, the query returns `true` (not calculated yet). Once the query is `false`, it means the task has been calculated.

I'm looking for a possibility for the observable to only emit once the returned value is `false`. So far I have tried with `.skipWhile` and `.filter`, but could not achieve the desired behaviour.

```
private calc = new Subject<T>();

calculate(id: number): Observable<T> {
    this.calcService.searchID(id).filter((x: boolean) => x == false)
         .subscribe((dat: boolean) => {
              this.calc.next(T);
    });
    return this.calc.share();
  }
```

or

```
calculate(id: number): Observable<T> {
    this.calcService.searchID(id).skipWhile((x: boolean) => x == true)
         .subscribe((dat: boolean) => {
              this.calc.next(T);
    });

    return this.calc.share();
  }
```

(I'm sorry for using == true/false)

Hope someone can give me a hint. I'm using RxJS 6.

**Edit:**
Sorry I missed something. `this.calcService.searchID(id)` is an HTTP request. And on every request it returns the boolean. So I might get `false` after 20 requests or after 100. It depends on the service how fast the calculation is. So I need a possibility to either wait until `false` comes back, or redo the request until I get `false`.

Comment: Http requests emit one value then completes. SkipWhile is usually used with an observable that emits multiple values. You should look at the example from angular about [exponential backoff technique](https://angular.io/guide/practical-observable-usage#exponential-backoff) and adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the service calls in an observable that will monitor the series of service calls. Service call will always emit a single value and complete.

Look at this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dwmwls?file=index.ts

One comment though: you should be careful with `first(predicate)` - even though it does the job, it will throw an error on completion if no value satisfying the predicate has been emitted. Otherwise you might use `filter(predicate)` + `take(1)`.

If you replace `first` with `skipWhile` + `take(1)` - you should be good too. There is often a couple of ways to achieve same result in rxjs.